# ¿Cómo podría insertar 100 registros a la vez en Mysql con php?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hola buenas alguien me podría ayudar, a insertar de manera más rapida 100 registros la vez, es que verán, cargo un excel con unos 9800 registro y me tarda aproximadamente unos 35 segundos en hacerme todos los insert, y por ahí, escuche que había una forma de insertar 100 registros a la vez, en vez de ir uno por uno, con un procedimiento batch o algo asi, y como aun soy muy novato en todo esto del desarrollo, no se me ocurre una alternativa a esto. Por cierto uso php con codeigniter 3 y mysql.

Hasta ahora lo que hago es lo siguiente.

en la vista solo tengo un formulario al que hay que poner un fichero excel csv,

se hace una llamada a la función de mi controlador.

```
 <form id="formDatosExcel" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="cargarDatosFicheroSubido">

     <div class="">
         <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-offset-2">
             <div class="input-group col-md-8">
                 <input class="mi-input" type="file" name="fileCajero" id="fileExcel"></span>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
     <br>

     <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-8">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Subir </button>
     </div>

 </form>
```

Que es la siguiente

```
 //controlador

public function cargarDatosFicheroSubido()
    {
        $config['upload_path']          = './files/';
        $config['allowed_types']        = 'csv';
        $config['max_size']             = 0;
        $ahora =  date("Y-n-j_H:i:s");
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
      if ($this->upload->do_upload('fileExcel')) {
          $datosCSV = $this->cargarFichero($_FILES['fileExcel']['tmp_name']);
      }
    }

    public function cargarFichero($rutaFichero)
    {
        if ($this->csvimport->get_array($rutaFichero, array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8))) {
            $csv_array = $this->csvimport->get_array();
            $datosCSV = [];
            foreach ($csv_array as $row) {
                if (empty($row[0]) || $row[0] == 0) continue;
                $row[2] = $this->formatDateFromExcelToMySQL($row[2]);
                $row[4] = $this->formatDateFromExcelToMySQL($row[4]);
                $row[6] = $this->formatDateFromExcelToMySQL($row[6]);
                $this->model->insertDataExcel($row);
            }
        }
    }


//model
    public function insertDataExcel($datosFicheroCSV)
    {
        $this->db->query(
            "INSERT INTO tabla (cam1, cam2, cam3 , cam4, cam5, cam6, cam7 , cam8, cam9 ) 
                VALUES ( ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ?, ? )",
            array(
                $datosFicheroCSV[0], $datosFicheroCSV[1], $datosFicheroCSV[2],
                $datosFicheroCSV[3], $datosFicheroCSV[4], $datosFicheroCSV[5],
                $datosFicheroCSV[6], $datosFicheroCSV[7], $datosFicheroCSV[8]
            )
        );
        
    }
```

Aun soy muy notavo y no sé como hacer para que tarde menos, actualmente 9800 registros me tarda como 35 segundos, me gustaría que tardara menos.
Alguna alternativa para esto, hago la inserción de uno a uno, y me gustaría poder hacerlos de 100 en 100 o de más.

Comment: Toma en cuenta que el tiempo de subida del archivo puede ser considerable, sobre todo en servicios residenciales, donde no es raro tener un 10% de la velocidad de descarga. A primera vista, en el código que muestras, no se apercibe mejora significativa.

Answer (score 1):

Usa una sentencia proporcionando varias listas de valores o marcas de remplazo `?`:

```
INSERT INTO tabla (lista de campos) VALUES
    (?, ?, ?),
    (?, ?, ?),
    ... (?, ?, ?)
```

Vas a necesitar un contador de registros para crear las marcas de remplazo `?` y un arreglo con todos los valores correspondientes a los registros a insertar.

En cada iteración del ciclo se incrementa el contador y se agregan los datos del registro al arreglo con [array_merge()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-merge.php). Solo cuando se tenga la cantidad de registros deseada se hace la inserción y se reinician tanto el contador como el arreglo de valores:

```
public function cargarFichero($rutaFichero)
{
    if ($this->csvimport->get_array($rutaFichero, array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8))) {

        // Definir máximo de registros a insertar
        $max = 100;
        // Inicializar contador de registros
        $records = 0;
        // Arreglo para acumular valores
        $data = [];
  
        $csv_array = $this->csvimport->get_array();
        $datosCSV = [];
        foreach ($csv_array as $row) {
            if (empty($row[0]) || $row[0] == 0) continue;
 
            $row[2] = $this->formatDateFromExcelToMySQL($row[2]);
            $row[4] = $this->formatDateFromExcelToMySQL($row[4]);
            $row[6] = $this->formatDateFromExcelToMySQL($row[6]);

            // Incrementar contador de registros
            $records ++;
            // Agregar datos al arreglo
            $data = array_merge($data, $row);

            // ¿Ya se acumuló el máximo de registros para insertar?
            if($records == $max) {
                // Envías el contador y los datos
                $this->model->insertDataExcel($records, $data);
                // Reinicias
                $records = 0;
                $data = [];
            }
        }
        // Verificar si quedaron datos por insertar
        if($records > 0) {
            $this->model->insertDataExcel($records, $data);
        }
    }
}
```

En el modelo usas [array_fill()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-fill.php) para generar las marcas de remplazo `?`, de acuerdo a la cantidad de registros y unir en una sola cadena con [implode()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php):

```
// Recibes la cantidad de registros a insertar y un arreglo con los datos
public function insertDataExcel($records, $data)
{
    // Creas la consulta
    $query = 'INSERT INTO tabla (cam1, cam2, cam3 , cam4, cam5, cam6, cam7 , cam8, cam9 ) VALUES ';
    // Agregar marcas de remplazo
    $query .= implode(', ', array_fill(0, $records, '(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'));

    // Ejecutar consulta
    $this->db->query($query, $data);
}
```

**Importante:** Dependiendo de la longitud de datos en cada registro, podrías incrementar el máximo de registros para insertar o, en caso de algún error, quizá deberías reducirlo; necesitas probar para ver que funcione correctamente y si mejora el rendimiento.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta y tu tiempo.